# Getting the axis labels in matplotlib not to go over the boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I try to plot this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latexTickSize = 18; latexLabelSize = 26

plt.xlabel('$t$', fontsize=latexLabelSize)    
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 5),\
['$-\pi$','$-\pi/2$','$0$','$\pi/2$','$\pi$'], fontsize=latexTickSize)
plt.xlim([-np.pi, np.pi])
plt.ylabel('$x(t)$', fontsize=latexLabelSize)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5), fontsize=18)
plt.ylim(-1.25, 1.25)

t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
plt.plot(t, np.cos(t))
```

This is what happens:
[image]

How do I get those horizontal and vertical axes to show WITHOUT shrinking any of the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague but I'm guessing that you are referring to the xlabel that is cut from the figure. There are two ways in which you can address this:

You can add `plt.thight_layout()`. This automatically adjusts the margins inorder to make everything fit onto the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latexTickSize = 18; latexLabelSize = 26

plt.xlabel('$t$', fontsize=latexLabelSize)    
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 5),\
['$-\pi$','$-\pi/2$','$0$','$\pi/2$','$\pi$'], fontsize=latexTickSize)
plt.xlim([-np.pi, np.pi])
plt.ylabel('$x(t)$', fontsize=latexLabelSize)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5), fontsize=18)
plt.ylim(-1.25, 1.25)

t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot(t, np.cos(t))import numpy as np
```

It produces this:
[Thight layout plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xstjU.png)

If this does not work you can manually edit the label padding by using `rcParams`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

latexTickSize = 18; latexLabelSize = 26
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelpad'] = -5 # default is 5
plt.xlabel('$t$', fontsize=latexLabelSize)    
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 5),\
['$-\pi$','$-\pi/2$','$0$','$\pi/2$','$\pi$'], fontsize=latexTickSize)
plt.xlim([-np.pi, np.pi])
plt.ylabel('$x(t)$', fontsize=latexLabelSize)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5), fontsize=18)
plt.ylim(-1.25, 1.25)


t = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
plt.plot(t, np.cos(t))
```

Which produces this:
[rcParams plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UnNI.png)

Personally I prefer `plt.tight_layout()`